# Randomly pick 4 elements from an array using c#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I am trying to use random function in C# to randomly pick four from an array `addetailsID` which has over six elements.

I am placing these randomly picked into an another array `strAdDetailsID`:

```
 string[] strAdDetailsID = new string[4];
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
     Random random = new Random();
     int index = random.Next(0, addetailsID.Length);
     value = addetailsID[index].ToString();
     strAdDetailsID[i] = value;
 }
```

Sometimes, I get two of the same values from the six elements. How can I get all four unique values to be picked?

Comment: Look up shuffling techniques (search Knuth, Fisher Yates). Shuffle the entire array and then just pick four in order.

Comment: To unique value, I think you will need to store list of `index` that you have got so far, and use it to check if new index has been used previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate 4 unique indices first, then pull the random values from the source array:

```
        string[] addetailsID = new string[20];  // this is the array I want to index into
        // generate the 4 unique indices into addetailsID
        Random random = new Random();
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        while (indices.Count < 4)
        {
            int index = random.Next(0, addetailsID.Length);
            if (indices.Count == 0 || !indices.Contains(index))
            {
                indices.Add(index);
            }
        }
        // now get the 4 random values of interest
        string[] strAdDetailsID = new string[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = indices[i];
            strAdDetailsID[i] = addetailsID[randomIndex];
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You might be better off [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) the array, and then choosing the first 4 elements.

Answer (score 7):

You could do it with LINQ with this method.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "There", "Are", "Many", "Elements", "To", "Arrays" };

foreach (var item in list.OrderBy(f => Guid.NewGuid()).Distinct().Take(4))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an issue with your placement of `Random random ...` but I believe you're attacking this the wrong way.

This could be solved by randomly ordering the source and taking the first 4 items.

```
var result = addetails.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(4).ToArray();
```

Assuming the contents of `addetails` are unique (like you imply), you will always get 4 unique values here.  Using random correctly, it's still possible to get repeats (because it's *random*).

Comment: oops... missed the C# 2.0 restriction.  The code here won't work but the concept will.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a list and remove the selected element from the list once it has been chosen.

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm works pretty well, and doesn't require extra storage or pre-shuffling. It does change the order of the source array, so if that's not feasible, then the pre-shuffling approach is best.

In pseudo-code:

```
result = []
For i = 0 to numItemsRequired:
    randomIndex = random number between i and source.length - 1
    result.add(source[randomIndex])
    swap(source[randomIndex], source[i])
```

In C#:

```
string[] strAdDetailsID = new string[4];
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int randIndex = rand.Next(i, adDetailsID.Length);
    strAddDetails[i] = adDetailsID[randIndex];

    string temp = adDetailsID[randIndex];
    adDetailsID[randIndex] = adDetailsID[i];
    adDetails[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should select random items one by one, not considering the already-picked items when selecting the next one. This must be faster than shuffling.

If the source list is small, you can just make a copy and remove the chosen items from it. Otherwise, you go like this:

(let `n` be the number of items in your array)

1. let S be the set of chosen indices; S = empty at the beginning
2. choose a random index `i` from 0 to `n-1-size(S)`
3. for each index from S that is smaller than `i` (starting from the smallest index!), add one to `i`
4. now `i` is a chosen index, add it to `S`.
5. return to step 2 until your set contains 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list instead and drop every item that is already used:

```
 List<string> addetailsID = new List<string>{"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

 string[] strAdDetailsID = new string[4];
 Random random = new Random();
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {

     int index = random.Next(0, addetailsID.Count);
     string value = addetailsID[index].ToString();
     addetailsID.RemoveAt(index);
     strAdDetailsID[i] = value;
 }

  strAdDetailsID.Dump();
```